# Error in Spring AOP Project

Tags: spring, spring-aop

I created a spring maven project, for a sample AOP exercise. I have also added
the required JAR files : `spring-aop.jar`.

Also, I tried it in another way, by adding dependencies for Spring AOP in the `pom.xml` file.

Still, I am getting an error when I declare the `@Aspect` annotation.

Comment: refer this : http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-aop-examples-advice/

Comment: Show us the POM. What does the error say - Unable to find the class ? After adding to pom, did you build the application via command prompt ? Add more details to refine your question. Abstract questions make life complicated.

Comment: POM is too large for the comment box here. Specifically,what should I show?

Comment: The comment box is small for a reason: you should update your question using the "edit" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need AspectJ and AspectJ Weaver

If still cant run, right click your project->configure->convert to aspectj project.